# Socket.io doesn't work on android chrome 51

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, websocket, socket.io

Socket.io works flawlessly on desktop chrome, chromium and firefox, but not on chrome for android both standard and dev(51).

here's my code:

index.html:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="scripts/messenger.js"></script>
```

messenger.js

```
var socket = io.connect('localhost:3000');
socket.on('chat message incoming', (msg) =>
        this.incomingMessageHandler(JSON.parse(msg))
    )
socket.emit('chat message outgoing', JSON.stringify(message));
```

I've done everything exactly as in official socket.io tutorial. Any ideas what's going on?

Cheers, Wojtek

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it looks like you are connecting to `localhost:3000`, which might not point to a valid NodeJS server on your phone. Try changing that address to a valid address which has your application running. Also, it's preferable to add the protocol (`http://`) to the address.

Comment: I'm talking specifically about `var socket = io.connect('localhost:3000');`. I Find it hard to believe that part works on your android device.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't reach your app from your android phone's chrome because of the `CORS policy` of the browser. `socket.io` tries to connect `localhost:3000` but from your phone's browser you have to connect to your local ip something like this: `192.168.x.x`

So, the CORS policy stops your connection because these two URL's hosts are not the same.

To solve this issue you can add [cors dependency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to your app like this:

```
const app = require('express')();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
```

Or, you can sets the ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header like this:

```
app.options('*', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.send('ok');
});

app.use((req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
});
```