# Socket.io doesn't connect to localhost on android browsers

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to connect to a localhost through an android browser. Everything works fine if I connect it with the IP address like this:

```
socket = io.connect("192.168.20.2:3000");
```

However, the IP address will not be fixed so I want to connect it like this:

```
socket = io.connect("http://host.local:3000");
```

This works on my computer and apple mobile devices, but not android.

I've found this link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59461390/13303770) which seems to answer this problem, but the solutions aren't working.

I want to be able to access the server when I go to http://host.local/ on my browser. Even when I connect with the IP address I have to access the IP address for it to work on mobile.

EDIT: Turns out this is what I was looking for : https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49188/how-to-get-mdns-working-for-chrome-on-android

Unless there's been an update seems like what I want isn't possible

Comment: Can you describe which solutions you tried, and how each one didn't work?

Comment: I tried setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin', to *, which didn't do anything and I was never able to install CORS for unrelated problems, but probably because I'm using an old version of Node (which I unfortunately have to keep)